# How to update a document of a sharepoint list using UpdateListItems

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

I'm able to delete a document in a list using this piece of code:

```
// string fileRef = "folder/myplan.doc"
private void DeleteDocument(string fileRef, string listGuid)
{
    string strBatch = "<Method ID=\"1\" Cmd=\"Delete\">" +
        "<Field Name=\"ID\">1</Field>" +
        "<Field Name=\"FileRef\">" + fileRef + "</Field>" +
        "</Method>";

    XmlDocument xmlDoc = new System.Xml.XmlDocument();
    System.Xml.XmlElement elBatch = xmlDoc.CreateElement("Batch");
    elBatch.SetAttribute("OnError", "Continue");
    elBatch.SetAttribute("ListVersion", "1");
    elBatch.InnerXml = strBatch;

    try
    {
        XmlNode ndReturn = lists.UpdateListItems(listGuid, elBatch);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
}
```

As you can see, i have to specify the fileRef, this will tell sharepoint which file i would want to delete.

However, i'm not able to update the document name of a list the same way. There is no error returned, the name just doesn't get changed.

The credentials for "lists" web service is quite correct. That's what i can guaratee. The document specified in fileRef is correct too.

```
private void UpdateDocument(string fileRef, string listGuid, string newName)
{
    string strBatch = "<Method ID=\"1\" Cmd=\"Update\">" +
        "<Field Name=\"ID\">1</Field>" +
        "<Field Name=\"Title\">" + newName + "</Field>" +
        "<Field Name=\"FileRef\">" + fileRef + "</Field>" +
        "</Method>";

    XmlDocument xmlDoc = new System.Xml.XmlDocument();
    System.Xml.XmlElement elBatch = xmlDoc.CreateElement("Batch");
    elBatch.SetAttribute("OnError", "Continue");
    elBatch.SetAttribute("ListVersion", "1");
    elBatch.InnerXml = strBatch;

    try
    {
        XmlNode ndReturn = lists.UpdateListItems(listGuid, elBatch);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
}
```

I'm curious about the examples here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/lists.lists.updatelistitems.aspx because i don't see where to specify the document (its guid or its fileRef), both for update and delete. How sharepoint knows which document should be deleted/updated?

I'm doing anything wrong or misunderstanding something?

Anyone has ever been successful in updating a document please share your work.
Thanks

Comment: Exact dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/994173/how-do-i-rename-a-file-using-the-sharepoint-web-services

Comment: Thank you Alex. This is what i'm looking for. It worked for me. What i discovered is the ID of the file/document must be specified in ID field.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use BaseName instead of Title

```
string strBatch = "<Method ID=\"1\" Cmd=\"Update\">" + 
    "<Field Name=\"ID\">1</Field>" + 
    "<Field Name=\"BaseName\">" + newName + "</Field>" + 
    "<Field Name=\"FileRef\">" + fileRef + "</Field>" + 
    "</Method>";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
"<Field Name=\"ID\">1</Field>" +
```

You are setting the attributes of the item with the ID of 1